# SonarQube Temp Disk Space

Tags: sonarqube, diskspace, temp

I'm finding SonarQube is using a *lot* of disk space in it's temp directory. Is there some sort of clean-up routine that runs regularly to purge this?

```
--- /opt/codehaus/releases`/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1/temp -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        /..
   29.7GiB [######### ] /tmp                                                                                                                       
   92.0KiB [          ]  jffi6092968669040435416.tmp
   60.0KiB [          ]  liblz4-java2192651176366163015.so
   20.0KiB [          ] /tc e   
    4.0KiB [          ] /ror
    4.0KiB [          ]  sharedmemory
```

If not, does anyone have any advice on how to manage this? Restarting the service seems to clear it all, but I don't really want to have to write something that restarts it on a timer.

Using v5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This limitation will be fixed in 5.2. Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the inconvenience.
See http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6700