# Why does SonarQube 6.0 temp folder have large amount of old data in it (36GB total)?

Tags: sonarqube, diskspace, sonarqube-ops

Our SonarQube 6.0 instance has a "sonarqube-6.0/temp/ce" folder than contains 35.9GB of data.  The oldest data in that folder is almost 3 months old.  A graph of disk space usage over time is shown below.

[image: sonarqube disk space usage]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756718/sonarqube-5-1-temp-tmp-directory-fills-up-how-can-i-tell-what-can-be-deleted) suggests that this was fixed in SonarQube 5.1.2, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286848/sonarqube-temp-disk-space) says that it's fixed in SonarQube 5.2.  We are running SonarQube 6.0.

How can I configure SonarQube to automatically cleanup the temp directory to remove unnecessary files so that the server doesn't run into disk space issues?

Comment: The `temp/ce` folder contains 1,691 folders, all named with 19 numbers, like `9146917874371972338`.  Each folder contains a single .dat file and a single folder named with 18 digits.  Inside of that folder there are hundreds of files with either the .txt or the .pb extension.  In other words, there is no single key contributor to the disk space usage, but instead many small contributors.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: which OS is this running on ?

Comment: Windows operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the '*C: Label*' in your screenshot this seems to be running on Windows OS. If so you may be impacted by:

- [SONAR-9734](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9734) - *temp storage grows on Windows due to cache under temp/ce not cleaned up*

Comment: Yes, that accurately describes my problem. Thanks for linking me to this Nicolas. I see that it is currently n progress. I'll watch the issue to keep an eye on it.

Comment: @ASnyder : issue will be fixed in SonarQube v6.6 , you should accept this answer so it can benefit to other users experiencing similar symptoms